# Kendo UI grid: radio button and pagination issue

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented a simple Kendo UI grid with filtering and pagination. I have first column with radio button for each row, and obviously I should be able to select only one radio button at a time. However, when I change the page, the current selection gets cleared and when I come back to that page, I find no radio button selected!

This is my HTML table:

```
<table id="grid">
            <colgroup>
                <col />
                <col />
                <col />
                <col style="width:110px" />
                <col style="width:120px" />
                <col style="width:130px" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="select">Select</th>
                    <th data-field="make">Car Make</th>
                    <th data-field="model">Car Model</th>
                    <th data-field="year">Year</th>
                    <th data-field="category">Category</th>
                    <th data-field="airconditioner">Air Conditioner</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="rg" /></td>
                    <td>Volvo</td>
                    <td>S60</td>
                    <td>2010</td>
                    <td>Saloon</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <!-- Contains many similar rows with radio button -->
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
```

This is Kendo Grid configuration:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  sortable: true,
  pageable: {
    pageSize: 10
  },
  filterable: {
    mode: "row",
    extra: false
  }
});
```

Could anyone please tell me the way how to make it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/Selection/grid-selection-checkbox as it should work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the radio button or maybe i could say the whole row re-initialized and the selected value doesn't got stored anywhere but the grid, if you are using use checkbox you can bind the value to some field on your dataSource model. But for radio button i propose a workaround for your problem which is:

1. Create a view model using kendo observable object, and have something to store the current selected radio button
2. On every page change which is dataBound will be triggered do re-bind the grid to the view model

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/EliQo/2)

**Explanation :**

First of all i create dummy data and a view model there

```
var data = [
      {id:1,make:"volvo",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:2,make:"audi",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:3,make:"bmw",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:4,make:"ferari",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:5,make:"honda",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:6,make:"lamborghini",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:7,make:"toyota",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:8,make:"mazda",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"},
      {id:9,make:"viper",model:"S60",year:"2010",category:"saloon",airconditioner:"yes"}
    ];

var vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    selectedRow: null,
    select: function(){ console.log(vm.selectedRow); },
    datasource : new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: data,
        pageSize: 3
    }),
});
```

Second, i initialize the grid (with custom column template for radio button) and as you can see i have `data-bind='checked:selectedRow'` and `value='#:id#'` to store which row's radio button is being checked

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { title: "id", width: "50px", template: "<input type='radio' name='rg' value='#:id#'  data-bind='click:select, checked: selectedRow' />" },
      { field: "make", title: "Car Make", width: "130px" },
      { field: "model", title: "Car Model", width: "130px" },
      { field: "year", title: "Year", width: "130px" },
      { field: "category", title: "category", width: "130px" },
      { field: "category", title: "category", width: "130px" },
    ],
    dataBound: function(e){ 
      kendo.bind($("#grid"),vm);
    },
    dataSource: vm.datasource,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
      pageSize: 3
    },
    filterable: {
      mode: "row",
      extra: false
    }
});

kendo.bind($("#example"),vm);
```

But the trick is that every databound i re-bind the grid with the viewModel vm because every time go to next/prev page it got re-initialized so the newly created radio button automatically selected `dataBound: function(e){ kendo.bind($("#grid"),vm); }`

Comment: Ok it makes sense, but consider this scenario: what if user navigates to another page and doesn't select any radio? It is fine if I get ID of the selected radio, so is it possible to get it in the scenario I described above?

Comment: And also, does this dataBound event get called even on sorting and filtering of the data? Because that time also I need to save the state of the selected radio.

Comment: @PratikGaloria yes it does dataBound will get called on sorting and filtering, i only store the id of the selected radio so i think it is okay wheter you select/or doesn't select at all.

Comment: Great! one more thing, here you have provided javascript objects as a data, in my case it would be predefined html table, so your solution will work there too right?

Comment: @PratikGaloria i haven't met that kind of scenario yet therefore i cannot say for sure, using predefined table is supported so it's worth to give a try. Usually i work with remote rest service instead of dummyData like i provided above

Comment: That's fine, I will try it and update the post, thanks for your help.

Comment: @machun..it worked like a charm on predefined html table with a little tweak, thanks! one thing is still hard to understand for me is data-bind='click:select, checked: selectedRow', could you please explain how it works? I mean when you click on radio, how ID of that radio gets set to selectedRow? and how it checks on every page change that specific radio was selected?

Comment: @PratikGaloria select doesn't do anything the trick is combining value="#:id#" and data-bind="checked:selectedRow" will store the clicked value on the kendo observable. 1 more is dataBound will rebind it everytime you go filter/other page. the html will lost the value but by rebinding it to viewmodel you give the value from viewmodel to html again

Comment: Got it, kudos to you! Now I understood this viewmodel concept in Kendo. I will try the same with checkboxes and may post as another question if I can't do it with the same strategy, hope you don't mind.